# Save text from the clipboard to a file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I was trying out below code that should save clipboard text to a text file in Delphi XE6. The code runs fine but generates only junk values in the output file, even when the clipboard contains a copied text fragment. How can the code be changed to work properly?

```
function SaveClipboardTextDataToFile(
  sFileTo : string ) : boolean;
var
  ps1,
  ps2   : PChar;
  dwLen : DWord;
  tf    : TextFile;
  hData : THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  with Clipboard do
  begin
    try
      Open;
      if( HasFormat( CF_TEXT ) ) then
      begin
        hData :=
          GetClipboardData( CF_TEXT );

        ps1 := GlobalLock( hData );
        dwLen := GlobalSize( hData );

        ps2 := StrAlloc( 1 + dwLen );

        StrLCopy( ps2, ps1, dwLen );

        GlobalUnlock( hData );

        AssignFile( tf, sFileTo );
        ReWrite( tf );
        Write( tf, ps2 );
        CloseFile( tf );

        StrDispose( ps2 );

        Result := True;
      end;
    finally
      Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It will be *much* easier to use a `TStringList` ... `List.Text:= Clipboard.AsText; List.SaveToFile('C:\MyFile.txt');`

Comment: In addition to using 'AsText', and not using 'Write' file api, a simple assignment to a string variable of the locked PChar pointer will have the string data copied by the compiler.

Comment: Where did you get this code? It's really quite nasty. Always worth remembering that if you suck 15 year old code off the internet it is likely to be inappropriate. In this case you were hit by Unicode and legacy IO. And the pointless low level Win32 api calls. Oh, and the try is in the wrong place. Has to come after resource acquisition not before it. The lesson here is not to copy code without first understanding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see junk because `CF_TEXT` is ANSI. You request ANSI text, the OS converts the clipboard contents to ANSI, and you put it in unicode string. Use `CF_UNICODETEXT` for unicode applications.

Also consider the points raised in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Delphi XE6 then you can use some of the already implemented features

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.IOUtils,
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

function SaveClipboardTextDataToFile( const sFileTo : string ) : boolean;
var
  LClipboard : TClipboard;
  LContent : string;
begin
  // get the clipboard content as text
  LClipboard := TClipboard.Create;
  try
    LContent := LClipboard.AsText;
  finally
    LClipboard.Free;
  end;
  // save the text - if any - into a file
  if not LContent.IsEmpty
  then
    begin
      TFile.WriteAllText( sFileTo, LContent );
      Exit( True );
    end;

  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: You can just use the `Clipboard` singleton rather than explicitly instantiating `TClipboard`

Comment: This code can be greatly simplified: `Result := Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_UNICODETEXT); if Result then TFile.WriteAllText(sFileTo, Clipboard.AsText);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `[dcc32 Error] Undeclared identifier: 'CF_UNICODETEXT'`

Comment: @Sormanne `CF_UNICODETEXT` is a [Standard Clipboard Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168.aspx). If your version of Delphi does not define it, you can define it in your own code. Its numeric version is 13.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, This way? -> `Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13;`